# Queuing web service calls

Tags: c#, thread-safety, locking

Every call to the web service goes through a custom queuing system. This has a limit that is set to 1. Every call that enters the same time with another call is purged and not handled. Not sure if this is completely thread safe.

```
public void QueueForExecution(T value)
{
    lock (_queueLock)
    {
        if (_entryCount < _queueLimit)
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref _entryCount);
            Logger.Trace(String.Format("Running task queue item for {0}.", _methodName));

            Task.Run(() => RunTask(value));
        }
        else
        {
            lock (_queueItemLock)
            {
                _queuedExecutionValue = value;
            }
            Logger.Trace(String.Format("Task queue limit reached for {0} - queued request - overriding any previous queued items.", _methodName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any locking on `_queueItemLock` is happening inside a lock on `_queueLock` then you can consider this as thread safe.

If any access of `_entryCount` is done in a lock on `_queueLock` then you don't need the `Interlocked.Increment(ref _entryCount);` but you can just increment in the normal way.

If you by any chance are using C# 6.0 (VS 2015) you can use string interpolation by using the `$` operator without the need of calling `string.Format()` like so

```
Logger.Trace($"Running task queue item for {_methodName}.");
```

other than that there isn't much to say.